Using ggsurvfit, how to draw the first event at time = 0 (as in ggsurvplot)?
I use ggsurvfit to draw survival curves (because it is more convenient to use as a ggplot2 object for aesthetics customization) (cf graph 2), but how to force the plot to draw the first events occurring at time = 0 (events that already occurred at start of follow up in fact) ? (as ggsurvplot do, cf graph 1)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(survminer)
df <- data.frame(
  time = sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
  status = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
  sex = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

survfit2(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, df) %>% ggsurvplot() + labs(title = "ggsurvplot")
survfit2(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, df) %>% ggsurvfit() + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) + ggtitle("ggsurvfit")



The ggsurvplot() function from survminer does produce a ggplot object you can edit, it's just stored in a list. Save the output from ggsurvplot() as an object, and then access the ggplot object using $plot. E.g.
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)

df <- data.frame(
  time = sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
  status = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
  sex = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

mod <- survfit2(Surv(time,status) ~ sex, df) 
plt <- ggsurvplot(mod)
plt$plot +
  labs(title = "ggsurvplot") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))


thank you for providing this solution but I would like to keep working with ggsurvfit: in your example the risk table as disappeared (and does not appear with  + add_risktable()); nor does appear add_pvalue() for log rank result)
